# Automatic line break in \mbox

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I needed to define a macro with text in a `\mbox`-environment. However, now the text doesn't habe automatic line breaks in the mbox. Would there be some workaround such that the lines break for the text in `\mbox`-macro just as any normal text? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: the main point of a \mbox is to disable line breaking. Why do you use it?

Comment: remove the `\mbox`

Comment: The `\parbox` macro (requiring a specified width) is a box that line-breaks when the specified width is filled.